# Smart::Comments for Python?

Tags: python, debugging, printing, comments, introspection

Are there any Python packages that provide similar functionality to perl's [Smart::Comments](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Smart-Comments/lib/Smart/Comments.pm)?

It has a number of features, but its core functionality is to make specially prefixed comments evaluate and print the expressions in those comments when the program is run.

To take a simple example from the docs:

```
### Expected: 2 * $prediction
###      Got: $result
```

prints:

```
### Expected: 42
###      Got: 13
```

I've tried a number of debug priting packages for Python, and found that they all resulted in code that was too noisy, as the debug print statements were interspersed with the code.

[Smart::Comments](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Smart-Comments/lib/Smart/Comments.pm) lets me keep debug print statements in comments, where I can easily ignore them when I don't need to focus on them and focus on just the code instead.

Is there anything like this for Python?